# string interpolation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass in the value of a variable to a jQuery selector but I can't seem to get it right. Here is what I'm working with:

### jQuery

```
var state = $("<%= @state %>").selector;
```

that captures this value -> `"pending"`

I'm trying to pass that value into this selector:

### jQuery

```
$(".snitches-index-header + .tags-column .#{state}_count")
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass the string into the jQuery selector. But this is not working as I expect. What am I doing wrong so that the selector would read:

```
$(".snitches-index-header + .tags-column .pending_count")
```

but obviously use the variable state instead of `pending`?

Comment: use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `$(\`.snitches-index-header + .tags-column .${state}_count\`)` by using the same backticks *(instead of quotes)* you use in SO to hilight code `\``

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable with the string:

```
$(".snitches-index-header + .tags-column ." + state + "_count")
```

If you are trying to use a Template literal then you need to use backticks and the dollar sign not `#`:

```
$(`.snitches-index-header + .tags-column .${state}_count`)
```

Comment: Good documentation on [template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation)

Comment: Please note that Template literals are not supported by IE11

Answer (score 2):

its just basic js syntax issue.

```
  $(".snitches-index-header + .tags-column ."+state+"_count");
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with string interpolation.